# Write an empty string (or delete the field) with ADODB.recordset into Access DB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, adodb, recordset

I have this code:

```
ds("Fecha comienzo").Value = TextGridEditar.Text
```

Where ds is an ADODB.RecordSet, and TextGridEditar is a TextBox in VB.NET. I use the RecordSet to write into an Access DB.

If I have some text in the TextBox, it works perfect. But if there's nothing, an exception is thrown. I can't do this:

```
ds("Fecha comienzo").Value = ""
```

How can I write an empty string with the RecordSet? Or how can I delete that single value (not the entire row). I want to be allowed to put nothing (not NULL) on that field, or to erase the value of that field.

---

EDIT:
In VB (not .NET), this code works with the same Access DB, even with empty strings:

```
ds.Edit
ds("fecha comienzo") = textgrid
```

Where ds is dynaset type.

Comment: I think you've to remove field *constraints* in database (Ms-Access). (Something like allow Zero Length String. )

Comment: @AVD I don't think so. See my edit. The code worked on VB with dynaset.

Comment: Then create the Dynaset recordset in VB.NET.

Comment: @AVD I'd like to solve it this way, my code is part of a bigger project, and in the rest of the project they use the ADODB.RecordSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This is the answer:

```
 If (TextGridEditar.Text.Equals("")) Then
     ds("Fecha comienzo").Value = System.DBNull.Value
 Else
     ds("Fecha comienzo").Value = TextGridEditar.Text
 End If
```

System.DBNull.Value inserts an empty string in the Access table, not a NULL value.